# Porting a TCP Twisted app to the serial port

Tags: serial-port, twisted

I've been using Twisted for a while to connect a computer with some devices over the net. I wrote a custom Protocol and Factory.

```
factory = TModBusFactory()
reactor.listenTCP(9007, factory)
```

Now I'd like to connect the devices to the serial port of the server machine. As long as I know, no change in the protocol is needed but I need to switch from sending bytes over TCP to send them over the serial port.

How hard to do is this change? How can I change the code snippet in order to make it work?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Serial port setup looks like this:

```
from twisted.internet.serialport import SerialPort
from twisted.internet import reactor

factory = TModBusFactory()
protocol = factory.buildProtocol(None)
deviceName = "ttyS0"

port = SerialPort(protocol, deviceName, reactor)
```